# Haskell Beginner, Calling Functions by their Names

Tags: haskell, reflection

Trying the 99 puzzles to learning Haskell. A quality-of-life problem that I have is that every time I test a solution, I would write a function:

```
mySolutionForQuestion12 :: someFunctionType

testMySolutionForQuestion12 :: IO ()
testMySolutionForQuestion12 = do
    print "testMySolution"
    print $ mySolutionForQuestion12 "myInput1"
    print $ mySolutionForQuestion12 "myInput2"
    putStr "\n"

main = do
    -- neglected code to test solutions for question 1 up to 11 --
    testMySolutionForQuestion12
    ...

    -- instead I want to do something like --
    callAllFunctionsInThisFileByNameBeginningWith "test"
    -- , so that I only have to write one line of code instead of n lines --
```

To be able to be as lazy as possible, I would love to have a way to make my `main` automatically call all functions that begin with the 4 exact characters `test` in my `.hs` file.

Is this possible in Haskell? Coming from Python, for Python a dynamic language this is self evident, but for C or C++ this would need quite a workaround (I don't actually know how to do that in these languages)

I am wondering thus how would Haskellians (if this is a word?) approach this? Is there some "best practice" in this regard?

Answer (score 4):

Best practice is first to *not* test your functions by printing values to `IO`, but instead let a proper unit testing library do it. Apart from the dinosaur [HUnit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HUnit), the most established one is [QuickCheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck), which has its focus on *automatically* generating test cases using randomness (but can just as well be used for hard-coded inputs). It doesn't really address the issue you're asking about here, however there's a lot convenience tooling that has been designed for QuickCheck. I use [`tasty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty) as the framework from which the tests are called; it adds useful controlling mechanisms, command-line arguments, statistics etc. but you still need to explicitly list the tests in a `main` routine. (Which I personally consider a good thing!)

For automatically searching the source files for tests and running them, you may have a look at [doctest](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/doctest) instead.

Comment: I suggest mentioning `hunit` as well; it's just as classic as QuickCheck.

Comment: was already in the typing about it...

Comment: `fmap testMySolutionFor [1 .. 12]`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, as my problem is more on the side of asking for some minor hacks to help me while I am learning the basic of Haskell, I feel it better to keep a minimal usage of non-built-in support libraries which will certainly be helpful when I try to build projects with Haskell later on.

Comment: @ClémentDato, learning to use QuickCheck and tasty will be really helpful to you even as a beginner. In fact, learning to focus on testing will help you learn how to program *in such a manner that your code can be tested*. Furthermore, the details of *how* things like QuickCheck can discover functions in your modules with certain name patterns are not really things beginners should usually wade into. If you want, you can read up on Template Haskell, but I'll admit that as an experienced Haskeller that's something I've only recently begun to understand.

Comment: I'm much more familiar with QuickCheck than with HUnit, but I am curious why you call the latter a "dinosaur". When a specific sequence of operations turns up a bug, doesn't it make sense to include that in your test suite alongside property tests? Also, I'm finding it rather tricky to write property tests for Template Haskell code (say, `Lift` instances), whereas it's easy to write unit tests. Property tests would require moving the `Arbitrary` instance out of the main test module, explicitly sampling the generator to produce test cases, splicing those into a list or something, (cont)

Comment: (cont) handling the errors pretty much manually, and not getting any shrinks. Unless, of course there's some way to work around these problems.

Comment: @dfeuer a concrete example is nothing but a property that happens to not have any ∀-s in it. In other words, unit tests are a trivial special case of property tests. If you write them in a tasty-quickcheck suite, it'll automatically generate only one test case for it (because all cases are the same).

Comment: @leftaroundabout, yes, that's true. I've even used QuickCheck that way, but I felt like I was "cheating" because I did it to avoid learning the "right" way. But I guess that was sloppy thinking!